# dynamic rendering is not working in celleditor for new row

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have three selectonemenu. and  first selectonemenu has two value. on changing value of first selectonemenu. rendering of second or third selectonemenu logic is defined.
but ajax is not working .

below is the code

```
                  <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="Global" rendered="#{bean.type eq 'G'}"></h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="Country" rendered="#{bean.type eq 'C'}"></h:outputText>
              </f:facet>
              <f:facet name="input">
                <h:selectOneMenu id="listType" value="#{bean.type}" disabled="#{maintainIdentifierClass.id ne null}" >
                  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listType}"></f:selectItems>
                  <p:ajax event="change" update="rest_edit_local, rest_edit_global"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="clusterCodeEdit" for="listType" display="icon"></p:message>
              </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
        <p:cellEditor id="rest">
            <f:facet name="output" id="rest1">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.parent}"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet id="restrict" name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="rest_edit_global"
                    styleclass="dropdown-class"
                    value="#{bean.parent}"
                    rendered="#{bean.type eq 'G'}" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="#{msg['Dims.Mandatory']}" style="width:100%"
                    effect="fold" 
                    editable="true" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{maintainIdentifierClassBean.globalList}"></f:selectItems>
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="resEdit_global">
                    </p:ajax>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="resEdit_global" for="rest_edit_global" display="icon"></p:message>

                <h:selectOneMenu id="rest_edit_local" value="#{bean.parentBo}"
                    rendered="#{bean.type ne 'G'}" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="#{msg['Dims.Mandatory']}" style="width:100%" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.globalList}"></f:selectItems>
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="resEdit_local">
                    </p:ajax>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="resEdit_local" for="rest_edit_local" display="icon"></p:message>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
```

Comment: what error you get #Latif Samar ?

Comment: No error. just nothing happen. it is rendering only one which is default one. after change event it should render other but it not working

Comment: Please inspect network traffic, browser console, add a messages tag, run in development mode etc... 'not working' and 'nothing happen' is unhelpful

Comment: I get the same trouble. It seems that p:ajax doesn't work inside p:cellEditor input controls such as p:selectOneMenu.